# Why #line directives are not processed inside false #if in clang?

Tags: c, clang, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

Consider the following `test.c`:

```
int main(void)
{
  int a;
#if 1==0
#line 1 "test.c"
#endif
  a = 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Note, that `#if` condition is false here.

I need to make so, that after performing the following commands the output will not be empty:

```
clang -g test.c
objdump -D a.out >dis
sed -i 's/line 1/line 2/' test.c
clang -g test.c
objdump -D a.out | diff dis -
```

To make the difference clear: if we change `1==0` to `1==1` in the example and run the above
commands, we get the following output:

```
749c749
<   33: 05 05 0a c8 05          add    $0x5c80a05,%eax
---
>   33: 05 05 0a c9 05          add    $0x5c90a05,%eax
```

In other words, I need to make `clang` always honor `#line` directives inside `#if`, even when it is false.

This is necessary to correctly compile output from ctangle.
Otherwise warnings, and debug line numbers are all wrong.

This should not be hard to do, because lines inside #if-#endif are
scanned anyway.

And #line directives outside #if-#endif (and inside - when it is true) are processed as necessary.

So, I just need to combine these two behaviors - carry out necessary
processing for #line directives inside #if-#endif.

Can somebody point me to the right direction how to change clang source? (any `clang` version will do)

Comment: The compiler is under strict instructions by the people who wrote the standard to ignore the content of sections of code skipped because of unsatisfied preprocessor directives (except to the extent necessary to determine nesting of `#if` etc).  Since the `#line` is skipped, it must be ignored.  If you want it processed, it must not be skipped.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.10.1 Conditional inclusion ¶6 _Each directive’s condition is checked in order. If it evaluates to false (zero), the group
that it controls is skipped: directives are processed only through the name that determines
the directive in order to keep track of the level of nested conditionals; the rest of the
directives’ preprocessing tokens are ignored, as are the other preprocessing tokens in the
group. Only the first group whose control condition evaluates to true (nonzero) is
processed._ […continued…]

Comment: […continuation…] _If none of the conditions evaluates to true, and there is a `#else` directive, the
group controlled by the `#else` is processed; lacking a `#else` directive, all the groups
until the `#endif` are skipped._  The term `group` is used to describe the lines controlled by `#if` (`#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, `#elif`, `#endif`) directives.

Comment: How about moving the `#line` out of the `#if` or also add it to `#else`?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Change it any way you like but then it ceases to be a C compiler, may cease to compile your code correctly, ceases to be something you can ask StackOverflow questions about, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be fixed in `ctangle.w` by outputting `#line` after each `#endif`, as follows:

```
@x
case identifier: a=id_lookup(id_first,id_loc,0)-name_dir;
  app_repl((a / 0400)+0200);
  app_repl(a % 0400); break;
@y
case identifier: a=id_lookup(id_first,id_loc,0)-name_dir;
  app_repl((a / 0400)+0200);
  app_repl(a % 0400);
  if (*buffer=='#' && id_first==buffer+1 && id_loc-id_first==5 && strncmp("endif",id_first,5)==0)
    {@<Insert the line number into |tok_mem|@>}
  break;
@z
```

Now we can use sections in preprocessor conditionals.
And we can use change-files which change preprocessor conditionals.