# #line directive in #ifdef block

Tags: c, gcc

How is the C processor/compiler supposed to handle code like this:

```
/*1:*/
#line 3 "line.w"

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(void)
{
printf("Before #ifdef: line %d of %s\n",__LINE__,__FILE__);
#ifdef STAT
printf("Inside #ifdef before section: line %d of %s\n",__LINE__,__FILE__);
/*2:*/
#line 19 "line.w"

printf("Inside section: line %d of %s\n",__LINE__,__FILE__);

/*:2*/
#line 12 "line.w"

printf("Inside #ifdef after section: line %d of %s\n",__LINE__,__FILE__);
#endif
printf("After #ifdef: line %d of %s\n",__LINE__,__FILE__);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*:1*/
```

C file `line.c` was created from CWEB file `line.w` by `ctangle`. Note the two `#line` directives inside the `#ifdef ... #endif` block.

When I run `gcc -E line.c -o line-noSTAT.i` and `gcc -E -DSTAT line.c -o line-STAT.i`, the two expanded `*.i` files differ in their output in the final `printf` after the `#endif`:

```
4d3
< # 31 "<command-line>"
6c5
< # 32 "<command-line>" 2
---
> # 1 "<command-line>" 2
1827,1828c1826,1835
< # 22 "line.w"
< printf("After #ifdef: line %d of %s\n",22,"line.w");
---
> 
> printf("Inside #ifdef before section: line %d of %s\n",11,"line.w");
> # 19 "line.w"
> 
> printf("Inside section: line %d of %s\n",20,"line.w");
> # 12 "line.w"
> 
> printf("Inside #ifdef after section: line %d of %s\n",13,"line.w");
> 
> printf("After #ifdef: line %d of %s\n",15,"line.w");
1830c1837
< # 23 "line.w" 3 4
---
> # 16 "line.w" 3 4
1832c1839
< # 23 "line.w"
---
> # 16 "line.w"
```

and the compiled program deviates, too:

```
$ gcc line.c
$ ./a.out 
Before #ifdef: line 9 of line.w
After #ifdef: line 22 of line.w
$ gcc -DSTAT line.c
$ ./a.out 
Before #ifdef: line 9 of line.w
Inside #ifdef before section: line 11 of line.w
Inside section: line 20 of line.w
Inside #ifdef after section: line 13 of line.w
After #ifdef: line 15 of line.w
```

Note the significant difference in the `After #ifdef` output.

<strike>AFAIKS, the **incorrect** `After #ifdef: line 22 of line.w` comes from the fact that the compiler/preprocessor picks the twenty-second line from `line.c`, not the fifteenth line from `line.w`.</strike>

This MWE was created with

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
```

but I have been informed that the MS Visual Studio debugger also has problems with similar (production) code. Also `Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)` produces these differing outcomes.

Shouldn't *all* code between `#ifdef STAT` and `#endif` be eliminated when `STAT` is not defined?

Comment: IMO it should not eliminate `#line` as it is a line in the source code, not the preprocessed file.

Comment: OK, if _both_ `#line` directives inside the `#ifdef` block would be preserved no matter if `STAT` is defined or not, then _both_ variants of the program should produce `After #ifdef: line 15 of line.w`, right?

Comment: I believe I understand what's happening!

Answer (score 1):

The C preprocessor – i.e., *any* variant, hence the consistent behaviour across systems – in fact **eliminates** the two `#line` statements in the `#ifdef` block, if `STAT` is undefined.

Starting from the *first* `#line 3 "line.w"` it continues through `line.c`, skips all of the `#ifdef` block, and catches the final `printf` in the twenty-second line of the C source file, which had been reset to `"line.w"` at the very beginning.

Duh, this appears to be a deficiency in **CWEB**'s `ctangle`, which should add a correct `#line` statement after the `#endif`.

---

An intermediate manual way to keep the line numbers in sync is:

1. Add `#line __LINE__` after `#endif` in the CWEB code `line.w`
2. Replace the concrete line number with `perl -pi -e "s/#line __LINE__/#line $./" line.w`
3. Convert CWEB to C with `ctangle line`
4. Compile C code with/out `-DSTAT`

Comment: The same problem was discussed years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138618/why-line-directives-are-not-processed-inside-false-if-in-clang and the solution presented there works nicely. I'll apply the change to `ctangle.w` ASAP.